# Simple function overloading not working as expected

Tags: typescript

In the following snippet:

```
interface ToArraySignature {
  (nodeList: NodeList): Array<Node>
  (collection: HTMLCollection): Array<Element>
}

const toArray: ToArraySignature = <ToArraySignature>(arrayLike: any) => {
  return [].slice.call(arrayLike)
}


toArray(document.body.children).forEach(element => {
  console.log(element.scrollTop)
})
```

toArray will *always* infer the first signature defined in the interface. So here, it will infer a NodeList even though it is really a HTMLCollection being passed. Thus, element.scrollTop will raise a compilation error as it only exists on the Element type.

How can this be fixed ?

Taking an argument of `NodeList | HTMLCollection` won't do because I would lose the strict relation between input and output.

Perhaps forcing the signature was wrong all along, but then, how can I have overloaded functions?

This is using typescript 1.8.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it always uses the first signature in this case, but you don't even need all of that anyhow.

Why not just doing this:

```
function toArray<T>(arrayLike: ArrayLike<T>): T[] {
    return [].slice.call(arrayLike);
}

toArray(document.body.children).forEach(element => {
    console.log(element.scrollTop)
});

toArray(document.getElementById("some_id").childNodes).forEach(node => {
    console.log(node.nodeName);
});
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20toArray%3CT%3E(arrayLike%3A%20ArrayLike%3CT%3E)%3A%20T%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%09return%20%5B%5D.slice.call(arrayLike)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AtoArray(document.body.children).forEach(element%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%09console.log(element.scrollTop)%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0AtoArray(document.getElementById(%22some_id%22).childNodes).forEach(node%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%09console.log(node.nodeName)%3B%0A%7D)%3B))